# Same code generating different goldens images on different machines

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I added a screenshot test for a screen on my flutter app and was adding my project on Circle CI, but for some reason, the image generated on the ci and on my machine are slightly different and the test is failing.

Bellow you can see the snippet of code of the test:

```dart
Future<BudgetList> loadState(WidgetTester tester) async {
    final screen = BudgetList();
    mockBloc = MockBloc();

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark(),
        home: Provider.value(
          value: mockBloc,
          child: screen,
        ),
      ),
    );

    return screen;
  }

  group('When the budget list is open', () {
    testWidgets('It should be displayed', (tester) async {
      await loadState(tester);

      await expectLater(
        find.byType(BudgetList),
        matchesGoldenFile('screenshots/with-items.png'),
      );
    });
  });
```

This is the image generated on my machine:
[image]

This is the image generated on circleci:
[image]

Does someone know how to make sure that the same golden image is generated every time independently of the machine?

Comment: can you please add screenshot that you actually see in your device or machines.

Comment: @AmitPrajapati, yes. Just updated the post.